# Can't access local host files on ios with charles proxy

Tags: ios, proxy, virtualhost, charles-proxy

Hi I have some issue With Charles Proxy and Ios device.

I try to test a local website on IOS device.

My website is a local virtual host: **website.local**, which call an distant serve **backend.dev**

My /etc/hosts look like that

```
10.0.1.XXX  backend.dev
127.0.0.1 website.local
```

I use Charle Proxy (Mac version) to be able to access local vhosts on mobile, it's work fine on Android, but not on Ios device (Ios7 / Ios8).

(My iOS device is correctly configure to use charles proxy,for example if I call google for exemple, I see the log in the sequence window of Charles, but not for my local virtual host)

Any idea ? Thank's

(My desktop computer is a Mac Os X 10.10.1 (Yosemite))